# MYSQL How to use a variable for the OutFile

Tags: mysql

I can't find how to use a variable as an an Outfile.

```
DECLARE wOutFile CHAR(256);
SET wOutFile = CONCAT('c/data/',wDateStr,'.csv');
SELECT * FROM sometable
INTO OUTFILE wOutFile;
```

The above renders an error on the last line.  The syntax parser in MySQL Workbench doesn't like the wOutFile on the last line.

Is there a way to tell the parser to use the contents of the variable?

I tried to search for a while but I must not be phrasing my question well.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make new statement from the strings, then you should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) -

```
DECLARE wOutFile CHAR(256);
SET wOutFile = CONCAT('c/data/',wDateStr,'.csv');

SET @var = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM sometable INTO OUTFILE ', wOutFile);
PREPARE stmt FROM @var;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Perhaps in a future release they might support variables.  The Prepared Statement approach required a lot more work, as I had other variables of various types in use in the Where clause.